# How to get Rake to execute all dependencies even if one fails

Tags: ruby, rake

Is there a way to coerce a Rake task to execute all of its dependencies before failing, even if one of those dependencies fails. For instance, in the following example I would like dep2 to execute in spite of dep1 failing.

```
task :dep1 do
  raise
end

task :dep2 do
  puts "dep2"
end

task :default => [:dep1, :dep2] do
  puts "default"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rescue` like this

```
task :dep1 do
  raise
  rescue
end

task :dep2 do
  puts "dep2"
end

task :default => [:dep1, :dep2] do
  puts "default"
end
```